# JSPDF Split does not behave as it should

Tags: html, css, jspdf, html2canvas

I have a big DIV at my html that I'm converting this using canvas (jspdf is doing this) taking a screenshot and putting the image ate the pdf.

My code is like this:

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
      pdf.addHTML(
        $('#myElement'),
        {
          format:'png',
          pagesplit: true
        },
        function(canvas) {
          console.log(canvas)
          $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop)
          pdf.save(pdfName);
        }
      );
```

The problem is that when I use "pagesplit = true" JSPDF split the image in some pages, it's nice! But the image becomes stretched totally disfigured.
There is some way to avoid image get stretched when using pagesplit?